# Pyautogui not running on Mac? (Catalina)

Tags: python, macos, macos-catalina, pyautogui

I'm trying to run the following from terminal on my mac, but what's happening is
the code appears to run (I don't get any error message), python (as an app) on my mac bounces on my dock as if to open and then it doesn't do anything and then it stops running. I can't tell if this is a permissions issue or a Mac Catalina issue or an issue with my code!

```
import pyautogui as gui
count= 0
gui.click(1080,521)
while count<5:
    gui.FAILSAFE=True
    gui.write(f'This is a test {count}x')
    count += 1
    gui.press('enter')
```

I've already tried to run the sudo command, I've also tried:

```
gui.moveTo(1080,521)
gui.dragTo(button='left')
```

in place of the gui.click command, but nothing seems to be working!
Help?

Comment: my case, only `gui.press('enter') ` works, funcions `click(box)`, `moveTo(x,y), dragTo()` didn't. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8):

In my case with Big Sir System Env I did

setting -> security & privacy -> Accessibility -> Terminal 'check'

It works well now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

Turns out this was a permissions issue - in Mac System Preferences I needed to give access to Terminal to control my mouse

Comment: On Big Sur, one must give terminal the permission in 'Accessibility'.