# The command pyautogui() is not working on Mac, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm new to python and I have this big problem: I have this simple script

```py
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time

    pyautogui.moveTo(100, 500, duration=1)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.moveTo(500, None, duration=1.5)
```

When I run the program it doesn't work, but it does not return error
However when I tried to take a screenshot with pyautogui it worked fine

I'm on macOS Ventura 13.4.1; I read that you have to have admin privileges on Pycharm to run pyautogui without problems but when I try "sudo" command it says "command not found", even though it should already be there (I already have admin privileges on my Mac, but with pyautogui not working, I really don't know what to think)
I have already checked terminal and pycharm on privacy on Settings
please help me, thank you

Comment: Lots of missing info here. Please include all the basics; is Python in the system PATH? What command are you running? Does `sudo python3` work? Is the error from the `sudo` command or from the `python` command? What is the exact error output? Does `sudo echo $PATH` differ from the output of `echo $PATH`, specifically regarding Python?

Comment: I have very limited knowledge on terminal commands, so I'll tell what I have done 
1) I used the command 
export PATH=/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH in the terminal, the echo command now says that python is in the PATH
2) sudo python3 does appear to work
3) there is no error output whatsoever: in fact it runs with error code 0... but it does not produce any result. I'm sorry if the information provided is insufficient, the most I could do was to copy and paste some commands in the terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyautogui not running on Mac? (Catalina)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62035751/pyautogui-not-running-on-mac-catalina)

Comment: In macOs Ventura in accessibility do not have the option to 'check' the Terminal; I did already give permission to monitor the inputs and the permission to control my computer. In the  "pointer control" options (in Accessibility) I do not have the option to 'check' the terminal